# Why can $-n\cdot \pi $ be changed to $n\cdot \pi $?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, pi

This task was just to solve this equation: $\cos2x=\cos4x$. I solved it correctly apart from one step. My book somehow changes $-n\cdot \pi $ to $n\cdot \pi $. How is it possible?

[image]

Comment: $n$ is an integer (you should write this down, you don't take arbitary multiples of $2\pi$, but integer multiples). If $n$ is an integer, so is $-n$. Therefore, you can omit the minus sign. Strictly speaking, you define a new dummy variable $k = -n$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. But since this is only a dummy variable, you could also call it $n$, instead of $k$.

Comment: The reader is supposed to understand that the set of all solutions of the equation is $\lbrace n \pi, n \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$, which is the same as $\lbrace -n \pi, n \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$. But I agree that the way your book is "explaining" that is rubbish.